# Help with basic programming

Tags: command-line, c

This issue I feel is more my understanding of pointers but here goes. I am suppose to create a system program in C that performs calculations as such math operator value1 value2. Example math + 1 2. This would produce 3 on the screen. I am having troubles comparing or summing the numbers. Here is what I have so far:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( int ac, char* args[] )
{
    int total;
    if (strcmp(*++args,"+") == 0)
    {

    }
    printf("Total= ", value1);
    if (strcmp(*args,"x") == 0)
        printf("multiply");
    if (strcmp(*args,"%") == 0)
        printf("modulus");
    if (strcmp(*args,"/") == 0)
        printf("divide");
    return 0;
}
```

I can do a string compare to get the operator but am having a hard time adding the two values. I have tried:

```c
int value1=atoi(*++args);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I voted for this question to be moved to SO (since it is more about programming than *nix. However, I can tell you that that code could use some serious tender love and care (please use braces for all conditional statements (read: gotofail), it looks like a `switch` statement might help out, indentation is your friend). Best of luck!

Comment: Unless I am wrong there is no harm in omitting braces when the if statement has only one line. As you can see I did use braces for the first if because I was using more than 1 line when testing. Also the indents are missing due to pasting it in and having to use four spaces for display as code.

Comment: Here, let me fix the indents for you. But you should *always* use braces for any block statement. In C, technically, you do not have to if it is one line, but read up on Apple's Gotofail if you think it's never caused harm.

Comment: If I were you, I'd a) never increment `args`, and b) if I absolutely had to increment `args`, increment it after the text has succeeded: `if (strcmp(*args), ..) {args++; .. }`. What inspired `args++` instead of using an index variable?

Comment: That was an example a professor used. Since I am only accepting three attributes (operator, val1, val2) didn't seem worth putting a loop.

Comment: @muru In this case we need to increment first, since the first program argument is args[1]; args[0] is the name of the program (similar to $0 in bash).

Comment: @muru Oh, I agree that shifting like that isn't really appropriate here, since there's a fixed number of arguments, each with a clear & fixed meaning. I was merely pointing out that we do need to skip over the program name in `args` somehow. But I guess there's not much point going into too much detail here; as HalosGhost said, this question really should be migrated to SO.

Comment: @PM2Ring yes, but that doesn't answer why such laziness is being presented, which is what I'm asking. And that answer is: bad prof.

Comment: @muru: Shifting `argv` is a common technique in older C code. Modern code tends to avoid it since it's painful to maintain and can easily cause bugs when you get it wrong. So it's not surprising to see it in a CS professor's code. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring Which is why continuing to do it is the sign of a bad prof.

Comment: @HalosGhost: The names `argc` and `argv` are *conventional* (and preferred), but the standard explicitly says that different names may be used. See [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 5.1.2.2.1.

Comment: @KeithThompson Indeed you are correct. I'm just used to seeing the conventional names. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*++args
```

Since you are doing a pre-increment `++` operator has higher precedence than `*` so the pointer is incremented and later you are dereferencing it which case you might never get to access the arguement which you actually intend to.

If you have input like

`+ 1 2`

We have

```
args[1] = +

args[2] = 1

args[3] = 2;
```

Why can't just access `atoi(args[2])`

You can do something like

```
int main(int argc, char **args)
{
    if(argc != 4)
    {
        printf("Fewer number of arguements\n");
        return 0;
    }

    else if((strcmp(args[1],"+")) == 0)
    {
      printf("Sum = %d\n",atoi(args[2]) + atoi(args[3]));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't suggest edits on this site yet, but the inconsistent indentation bugs me so! Fix it please? :D

Comment: Worked great and your explanation helped me understand what I was doing wrong.

Comment: @Gopi: This [suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6712148) was just rejected. I initially though I had made a blunder, but now I think perhaps not. It is unclear whether the indexes refer to `args` **before** or **after** the increment. Also, I have no idea what "Why can't just access..." means. Your answer would benefit from some clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of accessing the command line args via pointers, easily you can do this using array referencing. For example, `"math + 1 2"`, args[0] is `math`, args[1] will be `+` etc.

```
int main( int ac, char* args[] )
{
    if(ac < 4)
    {
        printf("Invalid Argument");
        return 0;
    }
    if (strcmp(args[1],"+") == 0)
    {
        int x = atoi(args[2]);
        int y = atoi(args[3]);
        printf("%d + %d = %d\n", x,y, x + y);
    }
    if (strcmp(args[1],"x") == 0)
    {
        int x = atoi(args[2]);
        int y = atoi(args[3]);
        printf("%d * %d = %d\n", x,y, x * y);
    }
    if (strcmp(args[1],"%") == 0)
    {
        int x = atoi(args[2]);
        int y = atoi(args[3]);
        if(y == 0)
            return 0;

        printf("%d %% %d = %d\n", x,y, x % y);
    }
    if (strcmp(args[1],"/") == 0)
    {
        int x = atoi(args[2]);
        int y = atoi(args[3]);

        if(y == 0)
            return 0;
        printf("%d / %d = %d\n", x,y, x / y);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, Worked like a charm.